# Apply a list of functions to a vector of values

Tags: r

I have a list of named vectors where each vector name corresponds to a function that I want to apply to each element of the vector.  I can accomplish this with the following code:

```
funs <- list(mean = c("mpg", "wt"), 
             var = c("qsec", "am"))

lapply(seq_along(funs), function(i){
  fun <- get(names(funs)[i])
  vars <- funs[[i]]
  
  res <- lapply(vars, function(x){
    fun(mtcars[[x]])
  })

})
```

Is there a better way to do the same thing?  The ideal solution would be, in order of importance, faster, more memory efficient, and more compact.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Switching to `data.table` will be the best thing for speed. A bit more context would help - is this output really in the format you want (nested list)? Are the functions you want to apply this way reliably aggregate functions? Is the format of the `funs` list fixed, or are you open to other input options?

Comment: All excellent questions.  The output can be in any format as long as (a) it is clear which functions were applied to which variables and (b) it can easily be converted to a data frame.  The functions I want to apply may either be aggregate functions or pairwise comparison functions.  The format of the funs list is currently fixed but I am open to other input options.  The fast and memory efficient criteria are the most important and I am open to any and all solutions that can improve upon my posted code in these two areas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using {purrr} you can do this :

```r
funs <- list(mean = c("mpg", "wt"), 
             var = c("qsec", "am"))
library(purrr)

imap(funs, ~ map(mtcars[.x], match.fun(.y)))
#> $mean
#> $mean$mpg
#> [1] 20.09062
#> 
#> $mean$wt
#> [1] 3.21725
#> 
#> 
#> $var
#> $var$qsec
#> [1] 3.193166
#> 
#> $var$am
#> [1] 0.2489919
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Or same result with base R :

```
Map(function(x,nm) lapply(mtcars[x], nm), funs, names(funs))
```

Comment: You should not use `get` unless you explicitly define the mode ie `get(.y, mode = 'function')` Otherwise it will throw an error if there is an object in the global environment with the name corresponding to any of the functions given. You should rather consider `match.fun(.y)`

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different option could be:

```
imap(funs,
     ~ mtcars %>%
      summarise(across(all_of(.x), ~ exec(!!.y, .))))

$mean
       mpg      wt
1 20.09062 3.21725

$var
      qsec        am
1 3.193166 0.2489919
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match.fun` to apply the function

```
imap(funs, ~  {f1 <- .y
         mtcars %>%
          summarise(across(all_of(.x), ~ match.fun(f1)(.)))})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `map2` function instead of `imap`:

```
library(purrr)

map2(funs, names(funs), ~ map_dbl(mtcars[.x], match.fun(.y)))

$mean
     mpg       wt 
20.09062  3.21725 

$var
     qsec        am 
3.1931661 0.2489919
```

Or `mapply` instead of `Map` in base R for a slightly better output (not simplified):

```
mapply(function(x, nm) sapply(mtcars[x], nm), funs, names(funs))

    mean     var      
mpg 20.09062 3.193166 
wt  3.21725  0.2489919
```